# How do I control the behavior of multiple child process using wait();

Tags: c++, c, unix, process, operating-system

I'm trying to create a program where a parent process does some computation and sends it over to the child process, The child process forks another process and does some more computation and sends it over to the child2 process for further processing.
I can't seem to figure out how to do this.
My Output is all messed up, sometimes child 2 runs before child 1. sometimes child 1 is finished last.
I want the other processes to wait for them.

This is i think how the code should look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[6];
    pipe(fd);
    pipe(fd + 2);
    pipe(fd + 4);

    pid_t id = fork();
    if (id == -1)
        return 1;
    if (id == 0)
    {
        wait(NULL);
        pid_t id2 = fork();
        if (id2 == -1)
            return 2;
        if (id2 == 0)
        {
            wait(NULL);
            pid_t id3 = fork();
            if (id3 == -1)
                return 2;
            if (id3 == 0)
            {

                wait(NULL);
                cout << "Child 3" << endl;
                // Read data from pipe and display
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Child 2" << endl;
                // Read Data from pipe and Display
                // Some Computation
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                }

                // Send Data to Child 3 through pipe
                wait(NULL);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Child 1" << endl;
            // Read Data from pipe

            // Some Computation
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            {
            }

            // Send Data to Child 2 through pipe
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Parent" << endl;
        // Some Computation
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
        }
        // Send Data to Child 1 through pipe
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: After the fork, there's no point in immediately calling `wait` in the child; it has nothing to wait for.

Comment: You must allow child 2 to run before (or concurrently with, or interleaved with) child 1, or you have a recipe for deadlock.  If child 1 produces more data than will fit in the pipe buffer, nothing will flow.  The idea of the pipe is that you don't have to worry about it; the pipe itself is your synchronization mechanism, and processes will block on reads as necessary.

Comment: Thank you, My understanding of it was wrong. I understand it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**wait**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) call returns as soon as *any child* in the same *process group* terminates (thus including any grandchildren).

When you want to wait for a *specific* process, use [**waitpid**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) instead. You should also check the exit code and the status.

Finally, you should wait for the child to exit *after* interacting with it via the pipe, not before, and you should not wait before starting the child.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

void die(const char* msg) {
  perror(msg);
  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int fd[6];
  pipe(fd);
  pipe(fd + 2);
  pipe(fd + 4);

  pid_t id = fork();
  if (id == -1)
    die("fork");
  if (id == 0) {
    pid_t id2 = fork();
    if (id2 == -1)
      die("fork 2");
    if (id2 == 0) {
      pid_t id3 = fork();
      if (id3 == -1)
        die("fork 3");
      if (id3 == 0) {
        cout << "Child 3" << endl;
        // Read data from pipe and display
        // Done. Nothing to wait for - just exit child 3
        cout << "Child 3 exiting" << endl;
      } else {
        cout << "Child 2" << endl;
        // Read Data from pipe and Display
        // Some Computation
        // Send Data to Child 3 through pipe
        // Wait for child 3 to finish before exiting child 2
        if (waitpid(id3, NULL, 0) < 0)
          die("waitpid 3");
        cout << "Child 2 exiting" << endl;
      }
    } else {
      cout << "Child 1" << endl;
      // Read Data from pipe
      // Some Computation
      // Send Data to Child 2 through pipe
      // Wait for child 2 to finish before exiting child 1
      if (waitpid(id2, NULL, 0) < 0)
        die("waitpid 2");
      cout << "Child 1 exiting" << endl;
    }
  } else {
    cout << "Parent" << endl;
    // Some Computation
    // Send Data to Child 1 through pipe
    // Wait for child 1 to finish before exiting parent
    if (waitpid(id, NULL, 0) < 0)
      die("waitpid 1");
    cout << "Parent exiting" << endl;
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
Parent
Child 1
Child 3
Child 2
Child 3 exiting
Child 2 exiting
Child 1 exiting
Parent exiting
```

Note that `Child 1`/`2`/`3` are printed in random order - that's because all children run in parallel, which is perfectly normal (we want the processes to run in parallel, it's the whole point of forking). The ordering will be enforced when reading/writing the pipes - the child reading from a pipe will wait until the data arrives.